# who is the "owner" of a newly mined BTC before its first transaction?

Tags: transactions, mining-pools

When a miner adds a new block to the bitcoin blockchain, effectively 900 new coins come into existence as I understand it.  the miner gets 6 of them as payment, but who 'gets paid" for the other 894?

What I mean by that is if I want to then purchase one of these new BTCs, with whom am I exchanging funds for my BTC as they are not yet "owned" by a single person - who is the "owner" until that first transaction occurs?

Comment: Where do the numbera 900 and 6 come from? The payout for finding a new block is currently 6.25 BTC + fees from that block's transactions. All of it goes to the mimer.

Answer (score 4):

The amount for the block reward is what is created, there is no additional created for any reason. If the block reward is 6.25 BTC, that is exactly what the miner is paid, and nobody else.